# Start Akregator in system tray

Tags: kde, linux-mint, tray

I have added Akregator to the list of startup applications, but it opens up window every time I boot into my system. Is there a way to make it not open the window and start silently in the system tray?

Comment: Does Akregator itself has a tray icon ?

Comment: @warl0ck, yes, it does.

Comment: So configure it, if it doesn't provide an option, fire a bug report or modify the source code, find the part of KSystemTrayIcon

Comment: @warl0ck, the question is about Akregator fetching feeds at boot up _without opening up its window_, and not about adding Akregator launcher to system tray.

Answer (score 2):

Starting akregator only in tray and without having to close the window is possible by calling

```
akregator --hide-mainwindow
```

The built-in help explains:

```
--hide-mainwindow         Hide main window on startup
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's any specific command-line or configuration option for Akregator, but I use a program called `alltray` to start up applications minimised in my XFCE tray.

e.g. I launch iceowl (debian standalone version of mozilla calendar) at login with a wrapper script that runs `exec /usr/bin/alltray --sticky /usr/bin/iceowl`

According to the man page, alltray works with Gnome, KDE, XFCE  4,  Fluxbox and WindowMaker.

Alltray is probably packaged already for your distro, or it can be found at http://alltray.trausch.us/

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. I do not see a way to prevent akregator from from opening it's window when you execute it directly. But if you enable it's tray, an minimize it to tray, log out, then log back in, kwin (or some combination of other things) remembers to start it minimized to tray. So basically the answer is to leave it minimized to tray when you log out. ( tested KDE 4.9 )